# Looping tr command to remove '\r' in multiple files in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, tr

I have about 260 files in a directory. How can I input these files one by one into some thing like this
`file` is an array name

```
file=input stream of multiple files 
x=0

LOOP
tr -d '\r'  file2
rm $file
mv file2 $file
x=$x+1
LOOP ends
```

Comment: You can do in-place edit, `perl -i -pe 'tr|\r||d' files*` and it is faster than repeated fork of `tr` command.

Comment: So basically you wanna delete all \r from each file in a directory ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `find` one-liner:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c '< "{}" tr -d "\r" > "{}.processed"' \;
```

This will create a carriage-returns-stripped copy of each file in the current working directory named as the original file with a `.processed` extension.

`tr` can read only from `stdin`, so it can't edit files in-place natively, however one hack is to redirect the content of a file to the `stdin` of a subshell and to redirect it as a here string to `tr`'s `stdin`, so that the file is read before the truncation necessary in order to write the file takes place:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c '<<< "$(< {})" tr -d "\r" > {}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`

```
perl -i -pe 'tr/\r//d' <your_file>
```

and with `find` for all files in your folder:

- *long version*

  ```
  find <your_path> -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 perl -i -pe 'tr/\r//d' {}
  ```
- *short version*

  ```
  find <your_path> -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec perl -i -pe 'tr/\r//d' {} \;
  ```

---

*Example*

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "line 1" "line 2" > foo
$ printf "%s\r\n%s\n" "line 1" "line 2" > bar

$ hexdump foo
0000000 696c 656e 3120 6c0a 6e69 2065 0a32     
000000e

$ hexdump bar
0000000 696c 656e 3120 0a0d 696c 656e 3220 000a
000000f

$ perl -i -pe 'tr/\r//d' bar

$ hexdump bar
0000000 696c 656e 3120 6c0a 6e69 2065 0a32     
000000e
```